# visualize spectral data in altair

Tags: python, visualization, altair, spectrogram

plot spectrograms/ spectral data in Altair.

I am attempting to plot a df that contains frequency bins as the column titles and time/frames as the index and each cell value is the magnitude of that frequency of that time.  How can I encode y-axis with column labels and have altair recognize that as an encoding channel.  Perhaps this is trivial task and I'm not conceptualizing a solution or this is a task that altair is not ideally suited in either case any recommendations are appreciated.

The Issue is my frequency bins are my columns in the df(and the column labels would be the y-axis) the index is the time axis (x) and I would use the color channel to encode the values of each cell.
How can I pass all the column titles as an encoding for the y axis? Or is their a method/strategu of reorienting the df? [spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag9RR.png)

I have a matplotlib version (as shown in the image) but Altair offers better interactivity and a couple of additional features that make it a more desirable option.  I have a lot of data to process and occasionally passing a visualization of specific objects is necessary.

As per Joel's request here's a  small sample of the dataset

Thanks

```
col_freq= [172.265625, 344.53125, 516.796875, 689.0625]

row_1 = [1610974057651.0325, 1261973870532.6091, \ 
234137860730.91223, 42549716015.37]
row_2 = [4741489056189.282, 3278778293422.225, \
160494114891.44345, 57040784835.97968]
row_3 = [198776867252.5261, 661886049124.3528, 188309227047.4264, \
124549622810.97015]

data = [row_1, row_2, row_3]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_freq)
df
```

here's the analysis code using scipy.spectrogram:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import scipy as sc
from scipy import fft, signal 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# this code produces the full df,  for x use any audio.wav file
sample_rate, audio_file = 
sc.io.wavfile.read('path/my_audio.wav')
size = 2048
window_func = signal.windows.hann(size)

def wave_to_spect(x, label):
    freq, time, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, sample_rate, 
       window=window_func, nperseg=len(window_func))
    col_name = [str(x) for x in freq]    
    df = pd.DataFrame(Sxx, index=col_name)
    df = df.T
    # visualize in matplotlib
    plt.pcolormesh(time, freq, np.log(Sxx), shading='gouraud')
    plt.title('Spectrogram) ' + label)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')    
    plt.show()

wave_to_spect(audio_file, "audio_car")
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data frame and the code you have tried so far so that someone can easily copy/paste it to try debugging?

Comment: To part 2 of your question I have not attempted to code in altair as I haven't come up with a method to  have altair recognize each column is a bin on the y axis and each row is a bin on the x axis.  the image above is from matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the sample data posted, here is how it can be done:

1. First `melt` your `DataFrame` (convert from wide to long format):

   ```
   df['time'] = df.index
   df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['time'])
   df.head()
   df.columns = ['time', 'freq', 'value']
   df.shape
   # (12, 3)
   df.head()
   #    time    freq    value
   #0   0   172.265625  1.610974e+12
   #1   1   172.265625  4.741489e+12
   #2   2   172.265625  1.987769e+11
   #3   0   344.53125   1.261974e+12
   #4   1   344.53125   3.278778e+12
   ```
2. Now visualize with `altair` using `mark_rect()` (use `color` channel to encode the `values`):

   ```
   alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x='time:O',
    y='freq:O',
    color='value:Q'
   )
   ```

to obtain the following figure:

[image]